# PriceBookEntry required field missing when creating QuoteLineItems

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am kind of new to CPQ and have been trying to create a Quote Line Item with no success.

```
Opportunity OpportunityOne = [SELECT Id, PriceBook2Id FROM Opportunity WHERE 
                              Id='0067F000008qOJzQAM' LIMIT 1];
Quote QuoteOne = [SELECT Id FROM Quote WHERE Name =:'TestQuote' LIMIT 1];
                      Product2 Product = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id 
                       =: '01t7F0000032Y89QAE' LIMIT 1];     

System.debug('Opportunity: '+OpportunityOne);
System.debug('Quote:'+QuoteOne);
System.debug('Product2:'+Product);  

QuoteLineItem QuoteLineItemOne = new QuoteLineItem();
QuoteLineItemOne.QuoteId = QuoteOne.Id;
QuoteLineItemOne.Quantity = 100;
QuoteLineItemOne.UnitPrice = 2000;
QuoteLineItemOne.Product2Id = Product.Id;
insert QuoteLineItemOne;
```

Why does it keep saying price book entry is missing. It is annoying. Insert fails and I see no object requiring a price book entry field.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to roll the apex API version back to version **38 or earlier** in order to create quote lines this way (using `product2Id` field). [As you can see in the object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_quotelineitem.htm) from version 39 onwards you'll need to populate the `pricebookentryId` field instead and leave `product2Id` null. To get the `pricebookEntryId` you'll just need an extra query eg.

```
PriceBookEntry pbe = [SELECT id FROM PricebookEntry 
      WHERE Product2Id =: Product.id AND Pricebook2Id =: OpportunityOne.pricebook2Id LIMIT 1];
```

Then just set the `pricebookentryId` field on your `quotelineitem` instead of `product2Id`